# SQL query to collect duplicate compound keys

Tags: sql, apache-spark, query-optimization

I'm working in PySpark, and using a lot of Spark SQL.  I'm trying to write a query that finds duplicate compound keys in a table.

I have a working query, but someone told me that this is a very inefficient query and I should rewrite it.  Here's the working query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        key0, key1, value,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY key0, key1) AS dups_count
    FROM code_adm1
)
SELECT key0, key1, value
FROM cte
WHERE dups_count > 1
ORDER BY key0 ASC, key1 ASC, value ASC
```

This is in fact a "check" query; I expect no results.  It is an error if the combination of `(key0, key1)` is not unique.  If it happens I want to find out how many duplicates there are, and what the values are, for debugging.  But unless it happens, running this is just a waste of time, so ideally it should be an efficient query.

Imagine that my dataframe contained this:

```
key0   key1   value
=====================
able   baker  campground
alex   bean   car
alpha  bravo  charlie
alpha  bravo  cindy
axe    book   cop
```

My correct query outputs:

```
alpha  bravo  charlie
alpha  bravo  cindy
```

I was told that to get a count of duplicate compound keys it would be much more efficient to use `COUNT(DISTINCT (key0, key1))` but this has the same effect as using `GROUP BY` and I get an error that I need to use an aggregate function on `value` (Spark suggested using `FIRST()`).

I *could* just stop collecting `value` but I would prefer a query that collects it.

Is there a way to rewrite my query so that it still works the same but is more efficient?  Also, if you can recommend a good resource on how to measure query efficiency and tune it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: about query efficiency the first step is usually investigate your execution plan. however I don't really think this currently working query is inefficient enough to worry about, how long does this query uaually take?

Comment: I'm mostly testing on small subsets of the actual data set.  I'm not sure how long it will take on the full data set.  I don't have numbers yet on how long it takes on the subset, but if you would find it useful, I'll get the numbers.  Would something like "X rows took Y seconds" be useful?

Comment: well then try it and check the execution plan, I ain't expert about `apache-spark` but this seem to be a small query without any join, so I don't really think this query will take forever if index is doing work.

Comment: "X rows took Y seconds" won't provide enough information, try it first and if it is too slow, add execution plan so we can actually help investigate the performance problem.

Comment: I've test your current query on my own database (oracle) and with index and it took 6 sec on 3 million rows table(which also produce a lot of dupe count). So I don't think you need to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is ostensibly fine.  You might find that a simple aggregation is faster:

```
SELECT key0, key1
FROM cte
GROUP BY key0, key1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This doesn't return the values but it returns any keys that have duplicates.